# Oracle Forms: executar sem navegador

Tags: oracle

Eu gostaria de executar o form no desktop mesmo, sem utilizar navegador para isso. 
Que é possível eu sei, pois já vi, mas como faço isto?

Estou utilizando o Oracle Forms, e ao executar um form, ele é executado em um navegador, que pode ser selecionado nas configurações do software. Porém, já vi o software ser executado em desktop mesmo, sem a utilização de um navegador.

Gostaria de saber como realizar essa mudança, e o que teria que instalar talvez para isto.

Comment: Dê mais informações. Só com isso é difícil de ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

**Versão oficial**:

Nas versões mais recentes de Oracle Forms não é possível arrancar Oracle Forms sem utilizar navegador.

No entanto, existe alternativas através de Java WebStart.

[Oracle Forms 10g sem navegador tutorial](http://develishdevelopment.wordpress.com/2011/12/27/oracle-forms-10-running-as-application-in-java-webstart/)

Não sendo oficialmente uma funcionalidade, conseguir estabilidade e fiabilidade pode ser tarefa complicada inicialmente.

Comment: olá!! agradeço a ajuda e atenção. Eu consegui efetuar a criação do arquivo .jnlp porém não consegui definir os forms para abrir desta forma. Onde eu defino isto? Não entendi muito bem esta parte... aguardo, obrigado!

Comment: aconteceu o seguinte erro ao tentar executar o form: 

InvalidArgumentException[ Argumentos inválidos fornecidos: {http://127.0.0.1:51510/uu0lsktKX7ezkXgkPnb1Eq3SmtCTiv3JZ41XiMMk4UhRhzVh, http://caps:8890/j2ee/webstart_10g.jnlp }]
 at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Bom por localhost (127.0.0.1) não vou lá de certeza.
O erro que te deu sugere que ele quer X argumentos do tipo Y e tu submeteste argumentos inválidos.
impossível ajudar-te mais sem ver código mas isso já foge a pergunta efetuada